# Ajuda com consulta SQL - eliminar um campo/ ocorrencia

Tags: sql-server, tsql, ciência-da-computação

Estou tentando realizar uma consulta onde todos os seres devem ser gerentes porém não devem ter trabalhado num projeto. Acontece que esse john é o único ser que trabalha e gerencia um projeto e eu devo eliminá-lo da consulta. Porém sem sucesso.

```
SELECT pessoa.primeiro_nome, projeto.nome
from pessoa INNER JOIN projeto 
ON pessoa.id = projeto.id and pessoa.id != projeto.pessoa_gerente_id
WHERE projeto.id <> projeto.pessoa_gerente_id
```

também tentei com este select mas john continua

```
select distinct * from pessoa
Join projeto on pessoa.id = projeto.pessoa_gerente_id
WHERE projeto.nome IS NOT NULL
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz sobre como resolver este problema?

[Aqui você pode conferir o script do banco](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wb2ZHnaxjqoeCHpRnL-CsYhQGWLt8WUC/view?usp=sharing)

Realizei uma consulta que retornava todos os seres com seus respectivos projetos, e alguns estavam nulos,
será que isso é uma inconsistência, ou está correto?

Comment: Aliás os seres devem ser gerentes, mas nunca devem ter trabalhado num projeto.

Answer (score 0):

> 4. Apresentar o nome dos gerentes que nunca trabalharam em projetos, além de gerenciá-los.

```
SELECT DISTINCT pes.primeiro_nome,
                pes.ultimo_nome
  FROM pessoa pes
 INNER JOIN projeto prj
    ON prj.pessoa_gerente_id = pes.id
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM projeto prj2
                   INNER JOIN pessoa_projeto pesprj
                      ON pesprj.pessoa_id = prj2.id
                   WHERE prj2.id <> prj.id)
```

Notei que no banco que você linkou não há registro na tabela `pessoa_projeto`, portanto todos os gerentes irão aparecer na `query`, já que não há ninguém alocado em nenhum projeto.